# How to have multiple rules file on Loki (Kubernetes)?

Tags: prometheus, grafana-loki, observability

I have a question that seems rather simple and obvious but for the life of me I can't make it work.
For starters my Observability stack is comprised of:

- Prometheus
- Thanos
- Loki
- Grafana
- Alertamanager

All running on kubernetes. For deployment/update I'm using Helm.

Now I want to have multiple rules files for Loki, one for each service, so that the alerts are more easily managed. Having one "*rules.yaml*" file with hundreds or thousands of lines doesn't sit right with me.

My current Loki backend & read configuration includes this:

```
  extraVolumeMounts: 
- name: loki-rules
  mountPath: "/etc/loki/rules/fake/loki"

- name: service1-rules
  mountPath: "/etc/loki/rules/fake/service1"
```

```
  extraVolumes:
    - name: service1-rules
      configMap:
        name: loki-service1-rules
    
    - name: loki-rules
      configMap:
        name: loki-rules
```

And I have both these files for the rules:

- loki-rules.yaml:

````
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: loki-rules
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  rules.yaml: |-
    groups:
      - name: loki-alerts
        interval: 1m
        rules:
          - alert: LokiInternalHighErrorRate
            expr: sum(rate({cluster="loki"} | logfmt | level="error"[1m])) by (pod) > 1
            for: 1m
            labels:
              severity: warning
            annotations:
              summary: Loki high internal error rate
              message: Loki internal error rate over last minute is {{ $value }} for pod '{{ $labels.pod }}' ```
````

And I have this one:

- rules-loki-service1.yml:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: loki-service1-rules
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  service1-rules.yaml: |-
    groups:
    - name: service1_alerts
      rules:
        - alert: "[service1] - Log level set to debug {{ $labels.instance }} - Warning"
          expr: |
            sum by(instance) (count_over_time({job="service1"} |= `[DEBUG]` [1m])) > 0
          for: 2h
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            summary: "[service1] - Log level set to debug {{ $labels.instance }}"
            description: "The number of service1 debug logs has been high for the last 2 hours on instance: {{ $labels.instance }}."
```

When I make the deployment of these rules I get no errors and everything looks good, but on Grafana's UI only the *rules.yaml* rules appear.

Does Loki not support multiple rules files or am I missing something ? Any help is greatly appreciated because like I said managing a filed with hundreds or thousands of lines with alerts seems to be a nightmare to manage.

Thank you!